# How to add a new field in POS Pivot reporting view. Odoo 14

Tags: python, sql, odoo

I want to add and group by a new field (state_id from partner_id) in the Model 'report.pos.order'.

I got this error :

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column s.partner_state_id does not exist
LINE 43:                 LEFT JOIN res_company_shop pst ON s.partner_...
^

Here is my code:

```
class PosOrderReport(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'report.pos.order'

    partner_state_id = fields.Many2one(string="State", related='partner_id.state_id', store=True)


        def _select(self):
        return """
            SELECT
                MIN(l.id) AS id,
                COUNT(*) AS nbr_lines,
                s.date_order AS date,
                SUM(l.qty) AS product_qty,
                SUM(l.qty * l.price_unit / CASE COALESCE(s.currency_rate, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE s.currency_rate END) AS price_sub_total,
                SUM(ROUND((l.qty * l.price_unit) * (100 - l.discount) / 100 / CASE COALESCE(s.currency_rate, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE s.currency_rate END, cu.decimal_places)) AS price_total,
                SUM((l.qty * l.price_unit) * (l.discount / 100) / CASE COALESCE(s.currency_rate, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE s.currency_rate END) AS total_discount,
                CASE
                    WHEN SUM(l.qty * u.factor) = 0 THEN NULL
                    ELSE (SUM(l.qty*l.price_unit / CASE COALESCE(s.currency_rate, 0) WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE s.currency_rate END)/SUM(l.qty * u.factor))::decimal
                END AS average_price,
                SUM(cast(to_char(date_trunc('day',s.date_order) - date_trunc('day',s.create_date),'DD') AS INT)) AS delay_validation,
                s.id as order_id,
                s.partner_id AS partner_id,
                s.user_id AS user_id,
                **s.partner_state_id AS partner_state_id,**
                s.company_id AS company_id,
                l.route_id AS route_id,
                s.sale_journal AS journal_id,
                l.product_id AS product_id,
                pt.categ_id AS product_categ_id,
                p.product_tmpl_id,
                ps.config_id,
                pt.pos_categ_id,
                s.pricelist_id,
                s.session_id,
                s.account_move IS NOT NULL AS invoiced
        """

    def _from(self):
        return """
            FROM pos_order_line AS l
                INNER JOIN pos_order s ON (s.id=l.order_id)
                LEFT JOIN product_product p ON (l.product_id=p.id)
                LEFT JOIN product_template pt ON (p.product_tmpl_id=pt.id)
                LEFT JOIN uom_uom u ON (u.id=pt.uom_id)
                LEFT JOIN pos_session ps ON (s.session_id=ps.id)
                LEFT JOIN res_company co ON (s.company_id=co.id)
                LEFT JOIN stock_location_route r ON (l.route_id=r.id)
                LEFT JOIN res_currency cu ON (co.currency_id=cu.id)
                **LEFT JOIN res_company_shop pst ON s.partner_state_id = pst.id**
        """

    def _group_by(self):
        return """
            GROUP BY
                s.id, s.date_order, s.partner_id,s.state, pt.categ_id,
                s.user_id, s.company_id,**s.partner_state_id**,l.route_id, s.sale_journal,
                s.pricelist_id, s.account_move, s.create_date, s.session_id,
                l.product_id,
                pt.categ_id, pt.pos_categ_id,
                p.product_tmpl_id,
                ps.config_id
        """
```

Any help please?
Thanks.